# given that $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $, evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^。}{x} $

Tags: limits

My idea is as follow，is it correct?

$$  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^。}{x} $$
$$ =   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin  \frac {x \cdot  \pi}{180} }{x} $$
$$ =   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x} {x} \cdot \frac{\pi} {180} $$
$$ = \frac{\pi}{180} (  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x} {x} )$$
$$ = \frac{\pi}{180} $$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x=1$

Comment: What does the symbol 。 mean?

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion degree

Comment: @dmtri thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You cannot simply pull a constant out of a $\sin$ function.  $\sin 2x \neq 2 \sin x$.

Instead you need to change variables.  Let $u = \frac{x\pi}{180}$, and rewrite everything in terms of $u$.  Then you will be able to get the result you want.  You have
$$ =   \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin  \frac {x \cdot  \pi}{180} }{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{u}}{x} $$
Multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac{\pi}{180}$ to get
$$\frac{\pi}{180} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{u}}{\frac{x\pi}{180}} = \frac{\pi}{180} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{u}}{u}$$
And then note that if $x \to 0$, $u \to 0$, so $ \lim_{x \to 0} =  \lim_{u \to 0}$, finally giving
$$\frac{\pi}{180} \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin{u}}{u} = \frac{\pi}{180}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have no idea how to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {sin u}{x} $even I rewrite it in terms of u. In terms of u, there is $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin \frac{u \cdot 180}{\pi}}{x} = 1$

Comment: Okay, I'll add more detail

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much！